# Jooq Generator: Groovy DSL fields not working

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

I am using the `nu.studer.jooq` plugin, jooq version 3.14.15.
I am trying to define synthetic primary keys like in the docs:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/codegen-database-synthetic-pks/

Error I get:
Invalid property: 'field' on extension 'jooq.main.generationTool.generator.database.syntheticObjects.primaryKeys.primaryKey', value: COLUMN1. Please check the current XSD: https://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.14.0.xsd.

```
jooq {
version = '3.14.15'
configurations {
    main {
        generationTool {

        }
        generator {
            name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
            database {
                syntheticObjects {
                    primaryKeys {
                        primaryKey {
                            tables = 'my_table'
                            fields {
                                field = 'column1'
                                field = 'column2'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Updated the description. Copied the code from the link (Gradle version) and replaced the table name and fields. Using the Programmatic approach I didn't have any issues. Seems to be a JAXB issue?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't see anything wrong at first sight, though I do remember there had been numerouds issues with the gradle DSL where a name is ambiguous. The problem seems to be mainly the fact that `field` is somehow wired directly to `primaryKey`...

Comment: For the record, this question has also been asked here: https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/308

Comment: This is rather blocking, because we have insertable views. I tried switching to the Programmatic approach and define a gradle task for it, but the task doesn't load custom classes (eg. for the converters). Do you know a workaround for that, or can I find somewhere a working gradle example with the Programmatic approach + custom classes. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem isn't related to jOOQ or the plugin by Etienne Studer, but to groovy. jOOQ isn't officially supporting this third party plugin, so I don't really know much about the groovy details... If you're licensed, I could have a look at a commercial support case. Otherwise, can you switch to kotlin? I think that might work better.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to configure a Gradle task with the Programmatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `fields = ['column1', 'column2']`